# Difference between "staggered" isometric and "normal" isometric tilemaps?

Tags: tiles, tilemap, isometric, tiled

The [Tiled Map Editor v0.9](http://mapeditor.org) recently added support for *staggered* tilemaps in addition to its usual isometric tilemap support.

What are the exact technical differences between these two types of isometric tilemaps? What are their advantages/disadvantages?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

"Staggered" refers to the jagged edges of isometric maps that have an overall rectangular shape. These maps emphasize the north/south and west/east axes, and often have North up (example: Civilization 2). Diamond maps on the other hand emphasize the diagonal orientation and movement. North is often at the top right (example: Simcity 2000). Also notice the different coordinate systems:

[image: Comparison]

**"Normal" or "diamond" isometric map:**

[image: Simcity 2000 screenshot]
Notice the overall shape of the map is a diamond.

**"Staggered" isometric map:**

[image: Civ 2 screenshot]
Notice the overal shape of the map is a (rough) rectangle

See also [this explanation](http://legendofmazzeroth.wikidot.com/staggered-isometric-maps):

> The math in terms of rendering both types of maps is similar but has its differences. Diamond maps are a bit more tricky particularly in terms of optimizing the render loop.
>
> Diamond maps are typically used in RTS and Tactical Combat types games whereas Staggered/Block maps tend to be used for RPG's and Turn-Based Strategy games.

In terms of the Tiled XML, staggered adds a new possible value for the attribute "orientation" of the map.

Finally, don't confuse these staggered maps with staggered *square* maps. The latter are a way to get pseudo-hexes:

[image: pseudo hexgrid]
Note how the tiles are squares, but movement and adjacencies conform to those of a hexgrid.

Comment: Sorry didn't see your answer while writing mine.  I like your answer better (more and prettier pictures).  For completeness, maybe we can add the note about the xml to yours and call it a day? ("In terms of the XML, staggered adds a new possible value for the attribute "orientation" of the map.")

Comment: @Cameron: Sure, how about this? :)

Comment: Lookin' good.   You got my upvote.

Comment: Awesome, I did not consider the map's orientation. Great choice of pictures btw.

Comment: What is the game in the example of normal isometric maps?

Comment: @Kroltan: Simcity 2000.

Comment: @Junuxx Neat! I was in doubt between that and Transport Tycoon. Thanks!